# An internal server error has occurred on publishing a site

Tags: site.com

I have created a form in site.com and previewing it works fine.
But on publishing it shows an error as

**"An internal server error has occurred Error ID:XXXXxxx-xx"**

I have checked the object permission and it has been given read,create permission.
If I publish it without form it works fine.

Site already have a form with lead object and it works fine.
But when I add another form with same object the error comes up on publishing it.

Is there some initial setting that I should follow before adding a form or when selecting a object for a form.

Comment: Internal server errors usually mean you're best off making a support case to salesforce. They have detailed logs and info that may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Internal Server Error means that an exception or error has been thrown in the underlying application server that Salesforce runs on, and there is nothing in place to handle this exception.

I've had the conversation with Salesforce support in the past about how I can debug these types of errors and the answer has always been that I can't.  I've also used my Salesforce contacts in the past to get the contents of the underlying log file, but its never been of any help as the stack trace is down in their application code, which I have no visibility of.

Usually I'll try adding and removing chunks of markup to see if I can narrow down the problem - you might try adding or removing fields from the form to see if its related to a specific field, but given that you have an existing form that is working this may not help.

Realistically, all you can do is raise this with Salesforce support and wait for an answer.

Comment: thanks bob!! Had a word with support.Hope so they reply  
soon